# ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(123)] NtOpenThread: {Access Denied} while trying to run an image down loader on Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

the code runs fine until it tries to access the directory.
any input is appreciated thanks

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import ast
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


opts = Options()

opts.add_argument("user-agent=chrome/23.0.1271")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")

url = 'https://s.aolcdn.com/os/ab/_cms/2020/09/09081722/568224.jpg'
directory = 'RAW'
FILETYPE = '.jpg'

r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)



def find_urls(url):
    driver.get(url)
    wait = input('loading...lmao')
    page = driver.page_source

    soup = Soup(page,'lxml')
    images = soup.find_all('img',{"src":True})

all_images = []

for image in images:
    image_src = image['src']
    print(image_src)
    
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_src)


Images = find_urls(url)





def save_img(Image,directory):
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

            
for i,link in enumerate(url):
    path = os.path.join(directory,'(:06).jpg'.format(i))
    try:
        ulib.urlretrieve(link,path)
    except:
        print('Failed:')

            
save_img(Images,directory)
```

I think might be how I access the directory but I'm running out of things to try I've checked the folder made sure to run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(123)] NtOpenThread: {Access Denied}
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* initiated thread was unable to read the system resource as access was denied.

---

### Root Cause

A common cause for **Access Denied** is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.

---

### Additional Consideration

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.